# Best method or algorithm to retrive the straight lines edges of an image mask

Tags: python, opencv, computer-vision, houghlinesp

I am trying to retrive the edges of an basket ball court. I was successful in creating a mask by using the histogram of the image. I would like to know what is the best approach to extract the straight lines from the image mask.

[image: Image mask]

I would like to extract the following edges marked in red as lines from the mask

[image]

Could some one tell me what is the best method or algorithm to use.  FYI, I tried houghlines but I get line segments that are very small.

[image]

Thank you

Comment: LineSegmentDetector is a very robust algorithm for both, mask images and general images. For masks you might also see good results with contour extraction and houghLines, or contour approximation, or approxPolyDp

Comment: I tried lineSegmentDetector as well, but I am still getting smaller segments instead of one big segment that scales the edge of the court completely.

Comment: Sure, since there are no big segments you will have to join them afterwards, by testing which segments might belong to the same bigger line. For example with a RANSAC test for inliers and outliers.

Comment: I would try running a few [dialtions followed by erosions](https://docs.opencv.org/3.4/db/df6/tutorial_erosion_dilatation.html) this will fill in gaps. Then I'd try contours or Houghlines.